# Does uniform convergence of analytic functions imply pointwise convergence in a bigger domain?

Tags: complex-analysis

I have a question that seems elementary but I can't figure out the answer.

Let $U\subset V\subset \mathbb{C}$ be open and connected. Then let $f_n,f$ be functions analytic and uniformly bounded in V. If $\{f_n\}_{n\ge0}\to f$ uniformly in $U$, does then $\{f_n\}_{n\ge0}\to f$ pointwise in $V$?

When I thought of that first I thought that it is obviously true and that it will be trivial to prove it. My idea was to prove it by contradiction but I cannot see the contradiction here. Is it something trivial?

Comment: I'm assuming that $V$ is connected. Can you show that there is a subsequence $\{ f_{n_{k}}\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ which converges on $V$, and that the subsequence must converge to $f$?

Comment: That actually might be possible. I need to check if I get sequential compactness in my setting. However this is one of the questions where one would expect a really simple answer.

Comment: By the way, yes, $V$ is connected. I'll add it. Thanks.

Comment: Have you ever heard of Paul Montel?

Comment: Equicontinuity should help.

Comment: @DanielFischer you are right. Montel's theorem nails it.